# How to download flights data for given year given airports from Bureau of Transportation Statistics?

Tags: python, r, database, statistics, data-science

I am not 100 % sure which thread of stack overflow to post this question and simply chose this thread to post the question.

I have been trying hours just to simply download a dataset and it is frustrating. So, I decided to seek help from already experienced users.

The problem is like this:

How to use python (web scraping) or R or bash wget or just click the menus or any other tools to download the data from the Bureau of Transportation Statistics with following criteria:

- year 2018
- airports from new york
- should have columns like departure arrival etc.

I looked at the website BTS(https://www.bts.gov/), it is too overwhelming for me to download the data with the given criteria.

Helps or instructions or snapshots are much appreciated.

Comment: Downloading the data is the main concern, tools and means are immaterial.

Comment: Which dataset are you trying to download?

Comment: @camille I am trying to download flights data for year 2018 from new york airports to all domestic airports.

Answer (score 1):

This could get you one step of the way there - but: https://www.transtats.bts.gov/ONTIME/Departures.aspx. 
There's also: https://www.flightstats.com/ (I've only heard of this, not done any digging. There's a historical and data export option on the dropdown on their homepage)

'All Statistics'
--then select the NYC airport, if all 3, may have to loop over those--
--carrier: this is a huge list, not sure if you need 'every' flight but I selected UA out of EWR--
'All months'
'All days'
'2018'

The biggest

[image: csv screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for effort, but looking for all destinantion from 3 airports take too much time. There must have been some simple UI or simple script to do this.

Comment: Did you look into www.flightstats.com?